# Jersey REST @ref change hostname

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, hateoas

How can I change the hostname of the given URI generated by the Jersey `@ref`?

I'm using Jersey REST to make a web service, with link to access different resources using the `@ref`, right now when I deploy the service in my local tomcat works fine (because uses `locahost:8080`), but doesn't work when is deployed in a public server (bla.com) because the link still has the hostname of localhost instead of bla.com

code using the `@ref`

```
@Ref(value = "res/{id}", style = Style.ABSOLUTE)
private URI uri;
```

web.xml

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.jersey.server.linking.LinkFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

**SOLUTION**:
After some research I found that the IP of the `@Ref` is picked from the running server (In my case it was a embedded Apache Tomcat), so to change the hostname you should change the Tomcat(any other server) configuration.